# String variable to stdin interface

Tags: node.js

I'd like to use the `stdin` parameter of this function: http://graspjs.com/docs/lib/.

The `grasp` function expects this parameter to be an object with the same interface that `process.stdin`. And what I have is a simple variable in memory of type string.

How can I give this variable to the stdin input of this function?

```
var grasp = require('grasp');
var sourceCode = 'if (condititon) { console.log("In the condition"); }';

grasp({
    args: '--equery condititon --replace true',
    stdin: SomethingLikeStringToStdin(sourceCode),
    callback: console.log 
});
```

Expected log:

```
if (true) { console.log("In the condition"); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`process.stdin`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin) is a [`Readable Stream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable). What `grasp` expects is a stream that it can read data from. To simulate this behavior, you can use a [`PassThrough`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_passthrough) stream: it's a stream that you can write strings of buffer to, and which will emit this data out, as any readable stream would.

Here is an usage example:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var passthrough = new stream.PassThrough();

grasp({ stdin: passthrough });
passthrough.push('some data');
passthrough.push('some other data');
passthrough.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

With Grasp 0.2.0, you can now use the new `input` option when using Grasp as a library, or use one of the two new helper functions: `grasp.search` and `grasp.replace`. This will allow you to do what you want without having to create a fake StdIn.

Documentation: http://graspjs.com/docs/lib/

Comment: Thank you for this new functionality @gkz :-)